# How to delete nested struct

Tags: matlab, object

I've a drawing object, say,

`obj = line(0,0);`

which can be deleted easily by

`delete(obj);`

However if the obj is nested, like

`obj.r = line(0,0);`

the obj cannot be deleted this way, or it will give this error:

```
Error using delete
Argument must contain a string.
```

So how do I delete this kind of nested object?

### Edit

```
obj.r = line(0,0);
obj.t = line(0,0);
obj.q = line(0,0);

works:
delete(obj.r);
delete(obj.t);
delete(obj.q);

doesn't work
delete(obj);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `obj` is a structure but is not nested (you `obj.r` and `obj.t` but not `obj.p.r`) `structfun` might do what you want, this should call `delete` on each field of `obj`.

```
structfun(@delete,obj)
```

If you have nesting it gets more complicated (depending on how many layers you have).  You might be able to do something with `fieldnames`, checking if any of the fields are themselves structures, then using `structfun` on those if so.